# Scroll WheelHorizontalView horizontally in espresso test

Tags: android, scrollview, android-espresso

I have a `WheelHorizontalView` and I want to scroll it horizontally to change the date when testing with espresso.

The `WheelHorizontalView` is from this library [antistatic.spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)

How can I achieve this?
I tried scrollTo() but it didn't work

Comment: Please try to format your text for better readability and link to the library you used if it is not well known. Also try providing a minimal code sample of what you did or tried to do so that others can better help you

Comment: This is because I edited your post and linked the library.

Comment: not yet, i still need an answer